# System.Windows.forms under ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

Hi i'm really a beginner in C# and still learning the principles of language
I'm working under ubuntu and compiling with gmcs and running with mono and I need to compile a program beginning with :
using System.Windows.forms;
using System.Drawing;

What should I do, It seems to be an assembly problem but I still don't know how that works ?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [mono-develop](http://monodevelop.com/) to start with.  It will configure the build and deployment for you.  It is easier this way at first.